# getJSON not being called properly

Tags: javascript, php, getjson

I'm a beginner,so kindly help me understand this.

I have made this sample test code:
(present in a external script file)

```
function validateForm()
{
     $.getJSON('database/grab_db.php', function(data) {
         alert("hello");
         return false;
        });
}
```

which is getting called from a form:

```
 <form id="form" action="users.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Also,I have changed the content type to `JSON` in the php file which returns the database

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

I know for a fact that the problem lies in the `validateForm()` method & the `getJSON` is not getting called properly.Tried putting `alert()` in `validateForm()`,outside of `getJSON` & it works well.
Also,its not the case of *Same Origin Policy* either, as all the files are local.

Thanks in advance.

## Edit:

Originally the `return false;` statement was outside of `getJSON`. But still it was not working.

Comment: Are there any errors displayed in browsers console? What is returned by network when 'database/grab_db.php' is called with $.getJSON?

Comment: I'm new to all this,but i think you might be talking about this:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined user_script.js:1
(anonymous function)`

Comment: Have you also included jQuery library into the same file where this external script file is included?

Comment: Kindly include this as an answer so that i can mark it as correct & reduce the **unanswered** list. Thanks btw,huge help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on console error provided by you in the comments `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined user_script.js:1 (anonymous function)`, it seems that you have not included jQuery library into the same file where this external script file is included.

Please included jQuery and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`validateForm` doesn't have a `return` statement (the one in the function you pass to `getJSON` is a different function).

This means the function returns `undefined`.

This means your event handler function also returns `undefined`.

This doesn't stop the default action of the submit event, so the form is still submitted.

Since Ajax is asynchronous, this means the form submits before the HTTP response has come back and the callback function has run.

Comment: I did try putting it outside of `getJSON` as well. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

`return false;` inside the callback of `$.getJSON` doesn't return false for `validateForm`.

You could pass the form element to `validateForm` function like below:

html:

```
<form id="form" action="users.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
```

js:

```
function validateForm(form)
{
     $.getJSON('database/grab_db.php', function(data) {
        // do some checking
        // if valid submit the form 
        form.submit(); 
     });
     // return false stop submitting the form
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried it outside as well(see the edit). But the `getJSON` is not getting called as i tried to put an `alert()` in side just for test purpose

Answer (score 0):

you should go with $.ajax(); in jquery

```
<form id="form" action="users.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Script:

```
function validateForm()
{
$.ajax({
type:"post",
url: "<?php echo database/grab_db.php ?>",
cache: false,
data: $("form").serialize(),
success: function(data)  // return data
{
alert(data);
}
});
return false;
}
```

In grab_db.php file

```
<?php 
$data = //fetch data

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: still not working..also,how would that change anything?

Comment: check in firebug console what kind of error it will returning error

Comment: replace url: "<?php echo 'database/grab_db.php' ?>",

and sure that url path exists true i.e file path